# Javascript - How to pull a WooCommerce variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to execute some PHP code that is using the WooCommerce variable to get the order ID.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'gen_order_meta_boxes');
function gen_order_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-gen',
        __( 'TESTNG' ),
        'order_meta_box_gen',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}

function order_meta_box_gen()
{
  echo '<button class="button save_order button-primary alert-mass">Generate</button>';
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'lolcats');
function lolcats()
{

    $order = new WC_Order($post_id);

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            jQuery(document).ready(function($)
            {
                $(".alert-mass").click(function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('<?php echo $order->get_order_number; ?>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

I can't seem to get it to return anything besides either null or 0.

Using something like this obviously works perfectly: `window.location="dhlgen.php?order=1234";` because I'm trying to pass it through the URL to a PHP function which uses it later.

This also seems to fail, but it returns 'false':

```
function lolcats($post_id)
{
    $order = new WC_Order($post_id);

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $(".alert-mass").click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = <?php echo json_encode($order->shipping_first_name); ?>;
                alert(data);
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: get_order_number is a function. You forggot the () at the end.  
$order->get_order_number(); should work.

Comment: I just get a return value of 0.

Comment: Are you getting value of $post_id?

Comment: Well even if I just use `alert('<?php echo $order; ?>');` I get a null value in the message box that pops up. It's very strange. This is the value I want returned: http://i.imgur.com/zM4iuNs.png

Comment: I should mention that I am executing this code in my **functions.php** file for WordPress which is then using WooCommerce functions. It seems it can't access the required data (hence why I get a null or 0), so perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Please update your post. It's hard to assume what you're doing. Make it complete as possible. what's `lolcats`? who's calling it?

Comment: No problem. Done. Refresh the page and check.

Comment: As mentioned before, check your $post_id.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by check the $post_id exactly?
 `http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2494&action=edit` is what my reference URL contains, so it is setting the post_id.

Comment: What is his value in the lolcat fonction ? Did you get it well from the url ?

Comment: In the lolcats function, I tried that by doing this `function lolcats($post_id)`. It's the same problem. Nothing is being sent through. It's either empty or 0. I want to say that the PHP code in the Javascript is probably failing.

Comment: Hum, for me it's look like you don't get your post value well before calling the lolcat function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144920/discussion-between-theo-bouveret-and-t0rxe).

Comment: Don't worry, I solved it. The solution is below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

```
function lolcats()
{
    global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $(".alert-mass").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('<?php echo $order_id; ?>');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```